# python Regex returns matched string, but also returns blanks where it could not match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

This is my input string :

```
str = '32 -3.723 +98.6 .357 0.86'
```

And my regex is :

```
print re.findall('[+-]?\d*\.?\d*',str)
```

It returns :

```
['32', '', '-3.723', '', '+98.6', '', '.357', '', '0.86', '']
```

What I could not understand why all these empty strings in between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what I could not understand why all these missing comes in between

All of the elements of your regex are optional, which means the regex can (and does) match the empty string.

```
[+-]? - ZERO or one matches
\d*   - ZERO or more matches
\.?   - ZERO or one matches
\d*   - ZERO or more matches
```

At every position in the input, the regex tries to find the longest match. For example, here

```
'32 -3.723 +98.6 .357 0.86'
   ^
```

the longest match is the empty string.

There are several ways to work around this. Rather than trying to shoehorn the regex into not matching empty strings, I personally would filter them out post-matching.

Comment: Thank you dear NPE for such a great insight. My mind boggled over this while searching for reasons, but failed. BTW, I am also going to filter them out post-matching.